# Angular - Solution for complex router params with link href

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, router

I have a card that I want the user to be able to open in a new tab by using mouse middle button. So for this purpose I added a link `<a>` with an `href` that is being automatically generated for each card. The problem is that the route I'm trying to navigate to takes as parameters some complex structures that cannot be passed directly in the route link. Sometimes the user just clicks on the card and the browser takes the link instead of the js method that passes the parameters. As a result the new route is loaded like there where no parameters (this is the correct behavior if it were in a new tab).

```js
const openDocument = function (){
  console.log('open doc in the same tab using custom router params');
  //params contains also a big array of numbers that cannot be passed in route
}
```

```css
.container{
   background-color: gray;
   width:200px;
   height: 200px;
   padding: 30px;
}

.global-link{
  position: absolute;
  background-color:red;
  min-width: 230px;
  min-height: 230px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: -15px;
 }

.card-container{
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <a class="global-link"></a>
    <div class="card-container" ng-click="openDocument()">     
    </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by preventing the onclick event default behavior. And then executing openDocument() method.

```
<a class="global-link" href="document/id" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); openDocument();"></a>
```

And it works really well because angular wont intercept the middle or right click, so you will be able to open in a new tab etc.